# Treat same tag, different namespace as the same

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xml-namespaces

I'm working on a project where I have xml files that contain html child nodes; some have the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` attribute, some do not. (in a previous process, a script checks the html sections for well-formedness, and uses htmltidy to clean them up if they need it)

is there anyway for an xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <html>
        <h1>html with no namespace</h1>
        <p>regular html.</p>
    </html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <h1>xhtml with namespace declaration</h1>
        <p>this has a ns, so all tags under it share that ns.</p>
    </html>
</root>
```

and a stylesheet like this :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <newroot>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </newroot>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="h1">
    <newhead>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </newhead>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
    <newpara>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </newpara>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to have the two html sets treated as the same? 
thanks, 
bp

Comment: As you can see from the answers, this is easily possible. However, I'd recommend not doing it; reject your source data as not valid xhtml, due to the absence of the namespace. Whatever system's responsible for providing that data should be fixed, otherwise you're going to keep running into problems like this. There are far too many systems outputting wrong data like this, because people take the shorter approach of working round it, rather than addressing it and having it fixed.

Comment: Continuing with @Flynn1179's sentiment, since you already have [htmltidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) in your toolchain, consider using its [output-xhtml](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#output-xhtml) option to clean-up the spotty namespace declarations to be `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` uniformly.

Comment: @Flynn1179, that is basically what I did. I modified my upstream stuff to add the xhtml namespace, and then added/used a namespace prefix for all the template rules. That seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @kjhughes I was using the ouput-xhtml with htmltidy. I wasn't previously, but the default output gave lots of irritating non-closing tags, so I added the output-html feature, which introduced the xhtml namespace. The disparity between the two was that some html nodes were well formed and not processed by htmltidy. Was easy enough to just add the ns as default. Thanks so much for the great/prompt replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple match patterns like this the clearest approach is probably to declare the html namespace in your stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="h">
```

and then list both alternatives in the template patterns

```
<xsl:template match="h1 | h:h1">
```

Answer (score 2):

My preferred approach to this is to preprocess documents in namespace A to put them in namespace B. After this simple step all documents will be in the same namespace so you can then use exactly the same transformation logic on both. This approach is far less disruptive to your transformation logic than attempting to handle both namespaces at every point of processing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using as *XPath* `tagname`, one can use:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='h1']">
```

So you match all tags `*` and then look by the constraint if the `local-name()` (the name does not include the namespace) is equal to `h1`. As a result both `ns1:h1` and `ns2:h1` are matched.

However if possible it is better to use `h1` over `*[local-name()='h1']`: some engines might will fail to optimize `*[local-name()='h1']` and thus start enumerating over all nodes and furthermore it is less readable and harder to maintain. Only giving advice...

Comment: You should probably use `local-name()` rather than `name()` - using `name()` would work for namespaced elements that use a default `xmlns="...."` but not for prefixed ones that used `xmlns:html="...."`, whereas `local-name()` would work for both.

Comment: @IanRoberts: true, sometimes libraries get a bit mixed up :s.